# AngularJS - Stop Event Propagation Firefox Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, events

here's code working perfectly on Chrome and Safari. In Firefox there's a problem with the **$event.stopPropagation()** invocation that doesn't has any effect

```
<md-content layout-padding style="height: 450px;padding: 24px;">
    <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="user in usersController.usersList" ng-click="usersController.onItemListUserPressed(user)">
        <ng-md-icon icon="person" size="100" style="margin-right:2%;"></ng-md-icon>
        <div class="md-list-item-text" >
          <h3>{{globalController.strings.Id}}: {{ user.ID_User }}</h3>
          <h4>{{globalController.strings.Code}}: {{ user.UserCode }}</h4>
          <p>{{globalController.strings.Username}}: {{ user.UserName }}</p>
          <div layout="row" layout-align="end end">
            <ng-md-icon icon="delete" style="fill: red;" size="30" ng-click="usersController.onButtonDeleteUserPressed(user, $event);$event.stopPropagation()"></ng-md-icon>
          </div>
          <md-divider ></md-divider>
      </div>
    </md-list-item>
```

I use $event.stopPropagation() to stop the invocation of the parent 
**ng-click="usersController.onItemListUserPressed(user)"** method,
when **ng-click="usersController.onButtonDeleteUserPressed(user, $event)"** is triggered.

Does anybody has ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Here's plunkr [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/k9qxQccQN6c3PMlJ7GPb?p=preview) but it works as expected!! So maybe it's something related to angular-material

Comment: well ... do one with angular-material